# ZK EventQueue.subscribe asynchronous behavior with callback

Tags: java, multithreading, zk

The ZK documentation for [EventQueue.subscribe](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/event/EventQueue.html#subscribe(org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.EventListener,%20org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.EventListener)) with two EventListeners states:

> Subscribes a synchronous or asynchronous listener to this event queue. A synchronous listener works the same as a normal event listener, while an asynchronous listener is executed asynchronously in an working thread.

However, the code example they give doesn't seem to support a synchronous listener at all:

```
eq.subscribe(
    new EventListener() {
        public void onEvent(Event evt) {
            // asynchronous
        }
    },
    new EventListener() {
        public void onEvent(Event evt) {
            // callback
        }
    }
);
```

It seems the first parameter is an `EventListener` which will be executed asynchronously, and the second parameter is an `EventListener` which will be executed synchronously, after the first completes. Is that interpretation correct?

Answer (score 0):

It's described in the documentation, just below the example :

> **Parameters:**
>   **listener** - the asynchronous listener to invoke when an event is received
>   **callback** - the callback listener, which will be invoked if the asynchronous listen has been invoked. Unlike the asynchronous listener, the callback listener works like a normal listener. You can access the current execution, and update the desktop.
>   **Version Difference:** since 5.0.8, the event argument is the same as the one passed to listener. In the prior version, it is always null for the callback listener.

So your interpretation is correct.